# Creating a string from pandas column and row data

Tags: python, pandas

I am interested in generating a string that is composed of pandas row and column data. Given the following pandas data frame I am interested only in generating a string from columns with positive values

```
index    A    B    C
  1      0    1    2
  2      0    0    3
  3      0    0    0
  4      1    0    0
```

I would like to create a new column that appends a string that lists which columns in a row were positive. Then I would drop all of the rows that the data came from:

```
index    Positives
  1       B-1, C-2
  2       C-3
  4       A-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `pd.DataFrame.apply` + `pd.Series.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 0, 0], [4, 1, 0, 0]],
                  columns=['index', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

def formatter(x):
    x = x[x > 0]
    return (x.index[1:].astype(str) + '-' + x[1:].astype(str))

df['Positives'] = df.apply(formatter, axis=1).apply(', '.join)

print(df)

   index  A  B  C  Positives
0      1  0  1  2   B-1, C-2
1      2  0  0  3        C-3
2      3  0  0  0          
3      4  1  0  0        A-1
```

If you need to filter out zero-length strings, you can use the fact that empty strings evaluate to `False` with `bool`:

```
res = df[df['Positives'].astype(bool)]

print(res)

   index  A  B  C  Positives
0      1  0  1  2   B-1, C-2
1      2  0  0  3        C-3
3      4  1  0  0        A-1
```

Comment: @user32185, No it doesn't. I've tested it with OP's data. Can you clarify?

Comment: With this df I got error
`df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])`

`df = df.reset_index()`

`df["index"] += 1`

Comment: See my update, it works. I'm using Pandas v0.23.0, Python 3.6.5. It works also with your suggest dataframe. Looks like you have a different configuration or haven't wiped clean your session.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the zeros with `np.NaN` to remove things you don't care about and `stack`. Then form the strings you want and `groupby.apply(list)`

```
import numpy as np

df = df.set_index('index') # if 'index' is not your index.

stacked = df.replace(0, np.NaN).stack().reset_index()
stacked['Positives'] = stacked['level_1'] + '-' + stacked[0].astype(int).astype('str')
stacked = stacked.groupby('index').Positives.apply(list).reset_index()
```

`stacked` is now:

```
   index   Positives
0      1  [B-1, C-2]
1      2       [C-3]
2      4       [A-1]
```

Or if you just want one string and not a list, change the last line:

```
stacked.groupby('index').Positives.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))).reset_index()
#   index Positives
#0      1  B-1, C-2
#1      2       C-3
#2      4       A-1
```

Comment: Hi I was just trying to work through your answer, could you explain what the purpose of 'level_1' is in your second line?

Comment: When you stack the `DataFrame` it will create a multi-index, with the column names as one of the index levels. `.reset_index()` then gets rid of the multIndex, which leaves you with a column named `level_1` that indicates the column name the non-zero value came from. The other column labeled `0` contains all of the non-zero values.